How to auto-detect config drift in dag Airflow when I change the task id name in VS Code?
In three step dag pipeline, I changed the task_id for second step and forgot to update it in third step Python code transform_load_data.
Is there way for any AI assistant to auto detect and highlight it to me in VS Code?
def transform_load_data(task_instance):
  ###### THIS IS THE CONFIG DRIFT - bug took me 2h, task_id was just slightly differently named
    data = task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids="extract_weather_data_for_my_city")###### THIS IS THE CONFIG DRIFT - bug took me 2h
    city = data["name"]
    sunset_time = datetime(data['sys']['sunset'] + data['timezone'])

    transformed_data = {"City": city,                       
                        "Sunset (Local Time)": sunset_time                        
                        }
    
    df_data.to_csv(f"s3bucketname")


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow', 
    'some  code'
    
}

with DAG('weather_dag',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval = '@daily',
        catchup=False) as dag:


        is_weather_api_ready = HttpSensor(
        task_id ='is_weather_api_ready',
        http_conn_id='weathermap_api',
        endpoint='/someapi'
        )

        extract_weather_data = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id = 'extract_weather_data_for_my_city',  ###### THIS IS THE CONFIG DRIFT - bug took me 2h
        http_conn_id = 'weathermap_api',
        endpoint='/someapi',
        method = 'GET',
        response_filter= lambda r: json.loads(r.text),
        )


        transform_load_weather_data = PythonOperator(
            task_id= 'transform_load_weather_data',
            python_callable=transform_load_data
        )

        is_weather_api_ready >> extract_weather_data >> transform_load_weather_data


Airflow Taskflow API will help make XCOM more pythonic, see https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html & https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-decorators

Hi Erjan. It seems that you're composing your questions on a mobile phone, or maybe using lower-case for stylistic purposes. This rather goes against the "documentation" style of Q&A we are trying to build here. If you could use technical writing, and an English spelling checker, it would be much appreciated
